# Cannot apply directory schema extension on User resource created through Graph Explorer

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Disclaimer: I am very new to all of this, so please be patient.  :)

My aim is to create a directory schema extension targeting the User resources of my O365 company directory. The extension is very simple with just 3 string fields. The idea is that every user in the directory should have this extension applied to their User object with specific values for the 3 fields it contains.

For this, I used the Graph Explorer, where I used my Admin tenant account to create a simple (domain verified) directory schema extension (domain_schemaname) with 3 fields, targeting the User resource.

I can confirm that the directory schema extension is created with status `Available`, using `/v1.0/schemaExtensions`.

After I updated the directory, I executed a Graph Explorer query to get the Extensions for myself (i.e. `/v1.0/me/extensions`), as well as of other users in the directory, however, the value of extensions node always returns an empty/null value(`[]`).

I am confused, since I was under the impression that once I create a directory schema extension for a particular resource target (i.e. the `user` resource), the schema extension would appear immediately in the properties of any existing or new instance of a `user` resource. Then, I would be able to `PATCH` the specific user with the values for the directory schema extension.

The issue is that when I try to add an extension to a User instance, through the Graph Explorer, it always creates an `openTypeExtension` type of extension, whereas I just want to assign the User just the contents of a directory schema extension already created in the `schemaExtensions` for my organization.

So, it seems that I am not able to use Graph Explorer to apply a directory schema extension to a specific User object.

Am I using the wrong tool for the job ?

Can you advise how do I populate all the users in my O365 directory with the particular directory schema extension and assign a unique value for every user ?

Do I need to use Microsoft Graph Client library and MSAL/ADAL to create a console app to create my directory schema extension and apply it to every user in my directory, and then update its value for every different user ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I recommend you update your question with some of the REST queries you are making in the Graph Explorer, and the subsequent outputted results. It will help everyone immensely.

Answer (score 0):

> I can confirm that the directory schema extension is created with status Available, using /v1.0/schemaExtensions.
>
> After I updated the directory, I executed a Graph Explorer query to get the Extensions for myself (i.e. /v1.0/me/extensions), as well as of other users in the directory, however, the value of extensions node always returns an empty/null value([]).

After creating the schema extension, we need to update the value of extension property before we can get its value.

For example, I register an schema extension like request below:

```
POST: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions
Content-type: application/json
authorization: bearer {access_token}

{
  "id": "coursesforuser",
  "description": "Graph Learn training courses extensions",
  "targetTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "courseId",
      "type": "Integer"
    },
    {
      "name": "courseName",
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "name": "courseType",
      "type": "String"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I update this property on the specific user:

```
PATHCH:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
Content-type: application/json
authorization: bearer {access_token}

{
    "exte5t2z4fr_coursesforuser":{
        "courseId":"123",
        "courseName":"New Managers",
        "courseType":"Online"
    }   
}
```

After that, we can get this property using the `$select` parameter:

```
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=exte5t2z4fr_coursesforuser
authorization: bearer {access_token}
```

More detail about the schema extension, you can follow link below:

[Add custom data to groups using schema extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_schema_groups)

Comment: Hi Fei Xue and thank you for the input. I tried it and I always get BadRequest.
This is the schema extension I have defined in my directory:

'code'{
            "id": "domain_TestMetadata1",
            "description": "Test Metadata 1",
            "targetTypes": [
                "User"
            ],
            "status": "Available",
            "owner": "74bf95dc-d299-4e44-9f52-b081677b2d3c",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "name": "AX",
                    "type": "String"
                }
            ]
        }

Comment: Would you mind sharing the exact request for update the value of extension the the detailed error message?